# Eloquent - callback when model fetch is complete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model 'Page' which has a one-to-many relation 'PageCustomField' (like the WordPress concept of a custom field).

This custom field model has two fields, key and value. What I would like to do is be able to do something like the following in a Twig template, where `page` is the parent Page model, `custom` is the collection of custom fields and `email` is the **key** to query custom field relations. The output would be the `value` field of the PageCustomField model.

```
{{ page.custom.email }}
```

I have achieved this by adding the following to the Page model:

```
public $custom = array();

public function extractCustomFields()
{
     foreach ($this->customFields as $customField) {
        $this->custom[$customField->key] = $customField->value;
     }

     return $this;
}
```

Called as follows:

```
$page = Page::where('slug', 'home')->firstOrFail()->extractCustomFields();
```

What I would prefer would be to have a callback which did this automatically, however, such as in the static boot method. Something like...

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // Extract PageCustomField relations into 'custom' array    
    static::fetched(function($model) {
        $model->extractCustomFields();
    });
}
```

Looking through the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model methods, I couldn't see a callback which would achieve this, but can it be done? I could override the `firstOrFail()` method, but would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for this case.

```
protected $customFields = [
    'email' = 'foo@bar.com'
];

public function getCustomAttribute() {
    return $this->customFields; // array
    //return (object)$this->customFields; // object
}
```

Call it:

```
$user = MyClass::find(1);

echo $user->custom['email']; // array
//echo $user->custom->email; // object
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'm looking for, but the issue is that the custom field data is still in a relation - I would currently have to do something like `$page->customFields()->where('key', 'email')->first()->value` to get the result. What I want to do is call `$page->customFields->email` to get the value of the custom field with key 'email'. I'd just like to streamline extracting the custom fields into an array or object accessible via the parent directly without a sub-query.

Comment: Actually, you're right - it can be achieved this way. Have updated above - thanks!